# Disable abilities to "create shortcut" and "send to desktop" through Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there any macro solution to eliminate the "Create Shortcut" and "Send to Desktop" options from right click? If not, is there any way other than messing with user permissions?

Thank you so much!

Comment: From right-clicking what?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables From right clicking the Excel workbook, unfortunately...

Comment: clicking it where? in its folder?

Answer (score 0):

Can't see why you would want to do that, but it's possible.
note that this will remove them for ***ALL*** operations, not just for your file.

To remove the right click create shortcut menu, save the code block as a **.REG** file, and run it

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew]
```

To remove the SendTo -> Desktop, search for all **.DeskLink** files, and delete them

to fix after:
recreate the shortcut menu:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew]
"Command"="rundll32.exe appwiz.cpl,NewLinkHere %1"
```

To recreate the Sendto -> desktop, create an empty file with the name **Desktop (create shortcut).DeskLink** in the users SendTo folder